# Call Already Created Checkbox With Created String

Tags: c#, string

I am wanting to use a string to call/second as a specific, already created checkbox:

```
string deadspin = "google"; // Changes each time in a for loop  
string **optionscommon** = "checkBoxGENOUT" + deadspin; // checkBoxGENOUTgoogle is a checkbox
int jimmy = Convert.ToInt32(**optionscommon**.Checked); // using checkBoxGENOUTmiso checkbox
```

I know placing a string where the name of the checkbox doesn't work.  So how, if I can, get this to work?

Comment: You want a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var jimmy = _checkBoxes[deadspin];
```

Where `_checkBoxes` is a `Dictionary<string, Checkbox>`?